# Azure Data Factory Exported CSV with UTF-8 Encoding not Showing Special Characters in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8, azure-data-factory

I am working on an ADF pipeline to export a CSV file from a Snowflake table. The table contains some fields with special characters (i.e. French language characters)

If I look at the CSV output in notepad, it looks perfect.

However, when opening in Excel, it is not showing the characters correctly.(ex: "é" appears as "Ã©")

If I change the encoding in Notepad to UTF-8-BOM, then Excel opens it correctly as expected. It also shows as expected if I import the data into Excel using the "Get Data" feature.

I do not see an option in ADF under encoding to set it to UTF-8-BOM, only UTF-8 or UTF-8 without BOM.

[image]

My question is basically this: How can I export the file to CSV format in such a way that the special characters will show correctly when a typical end user tries to open the CSV file in Excel?

Below is an example of how the file is currently configured.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the similar thing in my environment and got same result when I downloaded the copied blob in excel it's not Showing Special Characters in Excel. you can see below:

[image]

To achieve your goal, you need to specify the encoding as `UTF-8` in sink dataset.

[image]

After this when I copied the blob and open the CSV file in Excel it Is showing Special Characters appropriate format.

[image]

Comment: As shown in the screenshot I shared, the encoding is set to UTF-8. If I use the "Get Data" feature of excel and import as UTF-8, everything appears correctly. Are there any sort of settings in Excel or Windows needed to make it recognize UTF-8 by default?

Comment: yes there is setting in excel  where you can ser defult encoding